# Need to make a character move across my board (array)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, character

First off, I'm a complete newbie (I've been coding in Java for all of 2 months).

I've constructed the user defined game board with randomized "O" characters which act as cookies for the player defined as "<" to move across the board to "eat" those cookies.

How do I create a character on the board, initially open face facing left ">" and has the ability to move across the board using user defined movements?  This will create symbols ">", "V", "<", and "^" depending on the user move.

Here is the code for the board:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PacManTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char O;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input total rows:");
        int row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input total columns:");
        int column = input.nextInt();

        char board[][] = new char[row][column];

        for(int x = 0; x < board.length; x++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
            {
                double random = Math.random();
                if(random >.01 && random <=.10)
                {
                    board[x][i] = 'O';
                }

                else {
                    board[x][i] = '.';
                }

                System.out.print(board[x][i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You might get more favorable replies if you actually ask a question

Comment: or do you want [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, created a question.

Comment: Your question should be more specific.  What isn't working?  ...  Getting input from keystrokes (or mouse clicks)?  Updating the game state?  Displaying the new state?  The more specific your question, the more likely you will get an answer... or discover one on your own by searching.